# Comparing strings within CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, comparison, operators

I have a table with `character varying` fields like so -

```
Bill    Render     Refer        Supervise
        1194772160  
        1538359872  
        1194772160  
        1104026103  
        1104026103  
                                1831124015
        1740237197  1740237197  1740237197
```

Why is the below query returning empty strings -

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN render != bill THEN render
    END AS renderUnique
```

Comment: Because an empty string is not equal to bill.

Comment: Your question is broken while we cannot know whether you have `NULL` or empty strings (`''`), nor what your table definition allows, nor what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all rows contain `null` for the column `bill` the comparison:

```
render != bill
```

is equivalent to:

```
render != null
```

which returns `null`, so it is not `true` and the `case` statement returns `null`.
You could change it to:

```
select 
(CASE WHEN coalesce(render, '') != coalesce(bill, '') THEN render END) as renderUnique
```

Comment: This of course assumes that the columns do not contain `''`

Comment: If bill contained '' the comparison render != bill would return true, so the result of the CASE statement would not be null but the value of render.

Comment: the answers might be compared : [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e4dabdf104782719ed111c2d3a7ac416) (I think `renderunique1` wins)

Comment: if bill contains '' and render is null the comparison render != bill with the use of coalesce() on both sides will return false and the result of the CASE statement will be null. I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: This is the fiddle after fixing: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=72014f30013e0822833fd8eef5fdfe53 (had to remove `NOT`)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compare nulls as equal then use `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN render IS DISTINCT FROM bill THEN render
END AS renderUnique
```

Note that `x IS DISTINCT FROM y` roughly means x is not the same as y. Truth table should help:

```
| x    | y    | x distinct from y | x not distinct from y |
|------|------|-------------------|-----------------------|
| 1    | 1    | f                 | t                     |
| 1    | NULL | t                 | f                     |
| NULL | 1    | t                 | f                     |
| NULL | NULL | f                 | t                     |
| 1    | 2    | t                 | f                     |
```